# Return Specific ID in Postgres Column

Tags: postgresql

I am learning Postgres and have a basic question.

Let's say I have the following:

```
SELECT "id", count(*) AS "count"
            FROM "events" GROUP BY "id" ORDER BY "id"
```

How would I retrieve a specific id from this?  Like, ID 12345?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the filter is not on an aggregated value, won't adding it in WHERE clause be better (performance-wise)?

```
SELECT "id", count(*) AS "count"
            FROM "events" WHERE id = 12345 GROUP BY "id"
```

Probably the order by don't serve any purpose either.

Answer (score 0):

add a `having` clause like

```
SELECT "id", count(*) AS "count"
            FROM "events" GROUP BY "id" having id = 12345 ORDER BY "id"
```

see a sample here

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/09fc9/2